# Cards Click Event in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of cards created using SemanticUI framework. I also have few text fields on the side of the page. These cards represent a list of users. I am trying to implement the following. Once a user clicks on the card, it gets selected. Then, the user can click on either Edit or Delete button and a function OnClick of these buttons will be called. Now, how do I know which card was selected?

```
<a href="?cardId=val class = "ui card"></a>
```

I can now read the cardId as:

```
Request.QueryString["cardId"]
```

However, the page gets postback and I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. Please advise.

Comment: where you've cards in code?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `<a  onclick="myJsFunc(cardId);" href="#cardId=val class = "ui card"></a>`

and write the post ajax query within

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  //.. some URL change related stuffs if any
});

function myJsFunc(cardId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "//PartialViewExample?cardId=cardId,   // Call your C# function
        success: function (response) {
            // do the Dom Manipulation here and it will not postback
        }l
    });
}

C#
public ActionResult PartialViewExample(string cardId)  
{   

 // here the string parameter is same as your Request.QueryString["cardId"]

 // do your thing
    return PartialView();  
}
```

the reason being unless it is  `href="#abc" or href="javascript:void(0)"`
it is always & always going to do a postback .as it is in your case

Comment: Thanks Rohitas. Is there a way to handle this from C# code instead of JS? or the least call the c# function within the JS code you have there. Thanks again

Comment: hehe...I have **updated** the code  &.thanks I was actually in the same situation as you are as of now...but will help of **ajax** and **hashChange** I was able to overcome **postabacks**

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks brother

Comment: haha,,,,just a little experienced making & breaking codes . Let me know if the solution is the appropriate answer or If I still need to do lite modifications. Mark it as answer (the green tick ) if Correct.  :)

Comment: Thanks Rohitas. I have a feeling it is the exact what I am looking for. However, C# function never gets called. the URL changed without post back which is perfect. Also, I tried reading the URL passed parameter on some other button click in c# and it appears empty. What is your thought.

Comment: Hmmm you need to add some parameters to $.ajax  .. [Here](http://www.rubencanton.com/blog/2013/04/requesting-to-c-mvc-net-using-jquery-ajax.html) is a complete tutorial

Comment: Also You need to debug what XHR requests it is making on the browser developer console... It will show you the path of what c# controller action it is hitting. Until the status is 200. i.e. the routing is wrong & you wont hit the controller..

Comment: Can I have a look at your complete code ..both C# and JS.  I am sure you are almost there...just a bit of modification is required